# Express + Mocha, testing async middleware

Tags: unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I have auth.handler middleware that call some async function that I having problem to test using mocha & chai, using `done()` not helping either here, example code:

**middleware**

```
async function authHandler(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    const validCredential = await AuthService.verifyAccess(token)

    if (!validCredential) {
        next(new Error('Invalid credential')
    }

    next()
}
```

**test**

```
it('should return error', async () => {
    const token = 'invalid-token'
    const { req, res} = mockSetup(token)

    await authHandler(req, res, function next(error) => {
         expect(res.status).to.be.equal(500)
         expect(error.message).to.be.equal('invalid credential')
    })
})
```

Comment: right now nothing happens and the test times out?

Comment: side node, you call next() 2 times.